# Android ADT plugin problems

Tags: android

I got this problem when I am trying to do the ADT plugin step  and need some helps.

The error is as follow:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 15.0.1.v201111031820-219398 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 15.0.1.v201111031820-219398)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse SDK 3.7.1.M20110909-1335 (org.eclipse.sdk.ide 3.7.1.M20110909-1335)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    International Components for Unicode for Java (ICU4J) 4.4.2.v20110208 (com.ibm.icu 4.4.2.v20110208)
    International Components for Unicode for Java (ICU4J) 4.0.1.v20090822 (com.ibm.icu 4.0.1.v20090822)
    International Components for Unicode for Java (ICU4J) 4.0.1.v20090415 (com.ibm.icu 4.0.1.v20090415)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Development Tools 15.0.1.v201111031820-219398 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 15.0.1.v201111031820-219398)
    To: org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Java EMF Model Utilities 2.0.200.v200905140200 (org.eclipse.jem.util 2.0.200.v200905140200)
    To: bundle com.ibm.icu [3.8.1.1,4.1.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Java EMF Model Utilities 2.0.201.v201001252130 (org.eclipse.jem.util 2.0.201.v201001252130)
    To: bundle com.ibm.icu [3.8.1.1,4.1.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.1.r37x_v20110729-9gF7UHOxFtniV7mI3T556iZN9AU8bEZ1lHMcVK (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.7.1.r37x_v20110729-9gF7UHOxFtniV7mI3T556iZN9AU8bEZ1lHMcVK)
    To: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [3.7.1.r37x_v20110729-9DB5FmNFnFLSFCtLxnRfMqt15A4A]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse RCP 3.7.1.r37x_v20110729-9DB5FmNFnFLSFCtLxnRfMqt15A4A (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 3.7.1.r37x_v20110729-9DB5FmNFnFLSFCtLxnRfMqt15A4A)
    To: com.ibm.icu [4.4.2.v20110208]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Project SDK 3.7.1.r37x_v20110728-7Q7xAEDDePtVvBAYYD3z-il0ox7CoGe6mz-B8FDdVn0YR (org.eclipse.sdk.feature.group 3.7.1.r37x_v20110728-7Q7xAEDDePtVvBAYYD3z-il0ox7CoGe6mz-B8FDdVn0YR)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.7.1.r37x_v20110729-9gF7UHOxFtniV7mI3T556iZN9AU8bEZ1lHMcVK]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse SDK 3.7.1.M20110909-1335 (org.eclipse.sdk.ide 3.7.1.M20110909-1335)
    To: org.eclipse.sdk.feature.group [3.7.1.r37x_v20110728-7Q7xAEDDePtVvBAYYD3z-il0ox7CoGe6mz-B8FDdVn0YR]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Common Frameworks 1.1.300.v200904160730 (org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks 1.1.300.v200904160730)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.jem.util [2.0.100,3.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Structured Source Editor 1.1.101.v200908261807 (org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 1.1.101.v200908261807)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.wst.validation [1.2.0,1.3.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Structured Source Editor 1.1.102.v200910200227 (org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 1.1.102.v200910200227)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.wst.validation [1.2.0,1.3.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Validation Framework 1.2.102.v200905201610 (org.eclipse.wst.validation 1.2.102.v200905201610)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks [1.1.200,2.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Validation Framework 1.2.104.v200911120201 (org.eclipse.wst.validation 1.2.104.v200911120201)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks [1.1.200,2.0.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally I would suggest to download a lower version of eclipse (lower than 3.7). But 3.7 works  okay.

If you are just setting up your android sdk now... you should not be getting this problem.

if you are updating android environment through

you can follow these steps

help > check for updates

and accept the terms and install the updates.

remove the adt plug-in and reinstall it as suggested in developer site: http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

it will now install the eclipse supperted android tools such as DDMS etc (version 15.0....)

that should solve your problem.

Comment: thank you it is solved, when I open Android ADT first then run the program.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem today though versions of ADT was 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 and Eclipse SDK 3.7.2.M20120208-0800 (Indigo)

International Components for Unicode for Java (ICU4J) 4.4.2.v20110823...
International Components for Unicode for Java (ICU4J) 4.0.1.v20090822...
International Components for Unicode for Java (ICU4J) 4.4.2.v20090415...

OS: Windows Vista 32 bit

What solved it for me was ensuring my account had full permissions over the folders where eclipse was installed, then it installed without missing a beat.

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded the latest version of Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers, and installed the Android packages from http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse

I had the same error before, I was using an old IDE version with a newer version of the Android SDK, so that was the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted here and elsewhere, this is a permissions issue. Try changing the ownership of your installation of eclipse with `chown`:

`$ sudo chown -R root:$(id -g -n $(whoami)) /path/for/eclipse/stuff/`

where the `$(id -g -n $(whoami))` expression returns your primary group. From there, hopefully you'll have permissions over the stuff you need. This worked for me, but I'm not an expert.

**EDIT**:
Another possible cause for this is if the workspace you're using was created on a different computer or installation of Eclipse. Different computers and/or different installations of Eclipse can use different versions of plug-ins and JREs, leading to all sorts of problems.

That said, even if your workspace wasn't initialized with a different installation of Eclipse, try installing the plugin in a new, temporary workspace.

And for the record, I have found running Eclipse as root (`sudo eclipse`) to be a **terrible** idea. Pretty much nothing works - from just loading up to installing new plug-ins - when I've tried it.