# couldn't install android development tools on eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-emulator, eclipse-plugin

so I tried to install the android development tools but then I get this error:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for PHP Developers 1.3.1.20100916-1202 (epp.package.php 1.3.1.20100916-1202)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Eclipse UI 3.7.0.I20110602-0100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.7.0.I20110602-0100)
    Eclipse UI 3.6.1.M20100826-1330 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.1.M20100826-1330)
    Eclipse UI 3.6.2.M20110203-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2.M20110203-1100)
    Eclipse UI 3.6.0.I20100603-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.0.I20100603-1100)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Development Tools 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534)
    To: org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse IDE for PHP Developers 1.3.1.20100916-1202 (epp.package.php 1.3.1.20100916-1202)
    To: org.eclipse.epp.package.php.feature.feature.group [1.3.1.20100916-1202]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: EPP PHP Feature 1.3.1.20100916-1202 (org.eclipse.epp.package.php.feature.feature.group 1.3.1.20100916-1202)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.6.1.r361_v20100909-9gF78GrkFqw7GrsZnvz0JWNTeb6fue6896L]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.6.1.r361_v20100909-9gF78GrkFqw7GrsZnvz0JWNTeb6fue6896L (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.6.1.r361_v20100909-9gF78GrkFqw7GrsZnvz0JWNTeb6fue6896L)
    To: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [3.6.1.r361_v20100827-9OArFLdFjY-ThSQXmKvKz0_T]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse RCP 3.6.1.r361_v20100827-9OArFLdFjY-ThSQXmKvKz0_T (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 3.6.1.r361_v20100827-9OArFLdFjY-ThSQXmKvKz0_T)
    To: org.eclipse.ui [3.6.1.M20100826-1330]
```

What did I do wrong and how can I possibly resolve this error?

Comment: You can refer to [this question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420219/android-adt-plugin-problems/8420765#8420765

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced similar problem. I install the JDK (im using 1.7) and try to install Android SDK. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do have java environment installed in your system ... and eclipse knows its path right ?

Answer (score 0):

Use super user account to launch Eclipse in terminal, then install the ADT plugin in Eclipse:
$ sudo eclipse